# check existence of ftp file and parse exit code

Tags: bash, ftp, wget, exit-code

I need to check if a file exists via wget and test the exit code

Now, I'm running this:

```
wget -q --spider --ftp-user='ftpuser'--ftp-password='ftpassword' ftp://192.168.1.63/fileexists.txt
echo $? #0
```

and its `return code is 0`

**But in the case the file does not exist**

```
wget -q --spider --ftp-user='ftpuser'--ftp-password='ftpassword' ftp://192.168.1.63/filenotexist.txt
echo $? #0
```

its `return code is equal 0,` **even though there isn't**

So, I've tried **without --spider option** and I got **8 as exit code**, meaning that the file does not exist

But, if there is one the wget actually downloads it.
The problem is if I have a **big file** to 'check'..

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Use some other utility than `wget`. There is one called `lftp` which is reasonably scriptable.

Comment: -bash: lftp: command not found
... cannot use it

Comment: What version of `wget` is this?

Comment: GNU Wget 1.12..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using curl?

```
 curl -I --silent ftp://username:passwd@192.168.1.63/filenotexist.txt >/dev/null
```

$? is 0 if file exists, 
$? is not 0 if file doesn't exists.

Comment: I prefered wget, however I'm going to use this alternative
Thank you